# What is the workflow to pre-render your own openstreetmap raster map tiles (png)?

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

I discovered openstreetmap a week ago. After reading on the wiki for openstreetmap and other places I have decided that for my project I want to create and upload raster map tiles to my domain. I do not need all the zoom levels and have decided to use zoom level 1-11, which will drastically reduce the size needed for the pre-rendered tile image files, and to present the tiles on the client side using Leaflet. It looks to me that it should be possible to use either the planet file from openstreetmap as a startingpoint (or geofabrik.de), and then aquire a free map style (from somewhere) to use when I render the map tiles for the selected zoom levels.

I would prefer to pre-render the raster map tiles using windows, but if I have to install e.g. Ubuntu that is no problem.

What kind of free software do I have to install and use on my computer in order to create the raster map tiles for the zoom-level 1-11, from the planet osm file. Can I do this directly somehow without having to first import data from the planet file into a database?

How do I specify a map style to be used when creating the raster tiles (png) files, in the above process? Can I use the style used on openstreetmap.org? 
https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=11/57.4717/12.0087
Is there a list somewhere, showing a variety of free map styles that one can use for a project like this?

How do I aquire and install the nessesary map style files so the renderer software can apply those that map style to the image tiles produced?

I do not need a specific tile server, in the sense that some special software have to handle the tile request, in order to find out which image tiles to deliver to the client. Since I will pre-render all the map tiles (.png image files), these tiles will be uploaded to a folder on a webhotel, and will just be served the client via requests from Leaflet - which automatically request the correct image file URL's to be used for the selected zoom level and area to be displayed.

From what I can see I do not need to pre-render more than 5 592 405 tiles for the  whole world (zoom-level 1-11). I would guess this is will only require around 100 GB of storage.

Comment: This board is predominantly for solving specific coding issues, so your question is probably too wide - it would perhaps be more suitable on http://gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: Or http://help.openstreetmap.org/

Comment: Most likely you'll find all answers here: https://switch2osm.org/

Answer (score 3):

1. I'd definitely suggest Ubuntu over Windows as the OSM tools are more mature there.
2. On Ubuntu, I'd start from [here](https://switch2osm.org/manually-building-a-tile-server-18-04-lts/).  The "Stylesheet configuration" section of that covers "which map style to use".
3. You can I use the style used on openstreetmap.org, and in fact that's the default in the switch2osm guide linked above.
4. Perhaps the easiest way to search for other map styles of a similar type to OSM's "standard" map is to search github for project.mml.  Lots of other technologies exist for creating maps, though.
5. [This guide](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/User:SomeoneElse/Ubuntu_1804_tileserver_load#Force_Rendering_Tiles), which is very similar to the Switch2osm guide, has a section on force rendering tiles that you might find useful.
6. Given that your end goal is only "all the tiles" you don't need to load the whole planet into the database at once - you can do Africa, then Europe, then North America, and so on.  This will reduce the spec of the server needed.